# Tracing missing order numbers in the database, possibly even before they are "reserved"

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, sales-quote, increment-id

Hoping for someone to chime in who extensively knows the Magento database architecture inside out.

Missing order numbers. Example, in Magento, order number increments like:

100002410
100002411
100002412
100002414
100002415

I get that depending on the stage a customer is at on the website, an order number may get reserved for that transaction should they complete or return at a later time and complete.

I know that the reserved order numbers are stored in the `sales_flat_quote` table under `reserved_order_id` and those that complete are stored in the `sales_flat_order` table which should look pretty identical the Magento sales order grid in the backend.

I'm trying to locate any kind of information on what happened to missing order 100002413 in the above sequence.

It doesn't show up as an order in the backend (and subsequently is not within the `sales_flat_order` table) yet it was never reserved in the `sales_flat_quote` table neither (and many other order ids don't appear to be either).

What exactly is happening with these missing order numbers? Just what information can we trace against them in the database directly?

If you are wondering why I am searching for this, it is because we are trying to debug why we had a conversion via Google Shopping Adwords that never actually happened in Magento. No order at all for the conversion value logged (and is definitely not any of the sales that did occur on the same day) so I am wondering if the conversion value matches any cart total that perhaps is connected to this missing order number.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I just found the order number in `sales_flat_quote` reserved 7 days before that increment id were being matched against actual orders.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has a similar problem. Extension [Flagbit_MageHealth](https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-MageHealth) actually deletes old quotes to clean up the database. It led to difficulties in such investigations